# How to use pip to install module in Yocto recipe

Tags: pip, yocto, bitbake

I am updating my [pyadi-iio](https://pypi.org/project/pyadi-iio/) installation recipe from `0.0.14` to `0.0.15`. However the newer version no longer uses `setup.py` the new recommended way to install from source is `pip install .`.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757032/yocto-warrior-custom-bitbake-recipe-for-custom-python-wheel-file-cannot-install) question, I changed my recipe from:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
 
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "d258374fab29540e9f9ee38d36257a2e"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "fb6a9a47ed4af5a5c50819cf9973a93ea7148c2b70d775edb71bdf0e7da292b6"
 
PYPI_PACKAGE = "pyadi-iio"
 
inherit pypi setuptools3
 
RDEPENDS:${PN} += " python3-numpy"
```

to

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
 
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "ea94069ddb468988fe5a6465ecdf3ac1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "c3d04f027ea1d4660da825f2f2c2843f7a3d7876fa5e0c3f46725f70ccd08365"
 
PYPI_PACKAGE = "pyadi-iio"
 
inherit pypi
 
DEPENDS = "python3-pip-native"
 
RDEPENDS:${PN} += " python3-numpy"
 
do_install() {
    pip3 install .
}
```

However, I get an error saying `pip` can't access my `.cashe/pip` folder.

How do I install a python package without `setuptools3` and using `pip`?

Comment: Why are you using "pip3 install ." ? In your documentation, he applied this command inside the ~/pyadi-iio directory. So maybe instead of using just "." use the actual path of your directory using yocto variable like ${WORKDIR}/${PN}/. for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by not using `pip` and instead using `install` and `cp`.

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
 
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "ea94069ddb468988fe5a6465ecdf3ac1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "c3d04f027ea1d4660da825f2f2c2843f7a3d7876fa5e0c3f46725f70ccd08365"
 
PYPI_PACKAGE = "pyadi-iio"
 
inherit pypi
 
RDEPENDS:${PN} += " python3-numpy"
 
FILES:${PN} += "${libdir}/python3.10/site-packages/adi ${libdir}/python3.10/site-packages/pyadi_iio.egg-info"
 
DIRFILES = "1"
 
do_install() {
    install -m 777 -d ${D}${libdir}/python3.10/site-packages/
    cp -r ${S}/pyadi_iio.egg-info ${D}${libdir}/python3.10/site-packages/pyadi_iio.egg-info
    cp -r ${S}/adi ${D}${libdir}/python3.10/site-packages/adi
}
```

I was getting a file conflict error when building the image, adding `DIRFILES = "1"` fixed the problem based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763692/8672718) answer.

Comment: A great method for installing in lieu of an actual setup.py file. One suggestion I would add though is to also inherit `python_flit_core` or just `python3-dir` so that you can use `${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR}` so the recipe will be compatible when the Python3 version is upgraded.